# Automatically capitalize Datagrid input

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

Is there a way to automatically capitalize all (or to specific column) input to WPF Datagrid.
When I type to datagrid's cell and press Enter I need all the text in cell to become of upper case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test Character Casing"
                        Binding="{Binding Name}">
        <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="CharacterCasing" Value="Upper"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{  
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyList = new List<MyItem>();
    MyList.Add(new MyItem { Name = "" });
    MyList.Add(new MyItem { Name = "" });
    this.DataContext = this;
}
public List<MyItem> MyList { get; set; }
```

}

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: strange, but it not capitalizes first letter, only second and next

Comment: actually it capitalize first letter only if I double click to new cell, but if I click once to the row of cell I want to change, it starts with small letter

Comment: I will check this code and get back to u , mean while pls take a look at [msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5f55a966-8ea4-4e88-8ddf-9dee36273cfa/uppercase-on-cell-datagrid?forum=wpf)

Comment: @Dork,Pls add what was missing in my code , someone can use this.

Comment: @Dork, i think ,it will be with review team, i'm unable to do that from my side.